# Given a transitive model $M$, is it possible to have both $X \in M$ and $X^M \not = X$?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Suppose $M$ is a transitive model (set or proper class) of, say, $ZFC$ (weaken or strengthen the theory if you wish). Is it possible to have a set $X$ such that $X \in M$ but also $X^M \not = X$? Here $X^M = \{x \in M: \varphi^M(x)\}$ where $\varphi$ is the defining formula for $X$.

I think not but I can't prove it. I can't think of an example of such an $X$ either.

Comment: You should really be asking about formulas, not sets--a set will not have a unique "defining formula" (or may not have any at all!).

Comment: @Eric But there are situations where you want to compare $X$ (the set) with $X^M$ (the interpretation of $X$ in $M$), even when "there is no formula" describing $X$. For instance, we use "universally Baire" codes  to make sense of such sets. (There are wrinkles to all of this, naturally.)

Comment: @EricWofsey What would the strictly formula version of this be?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo when you say "the interpretation of $X$ in $M$", does that mean the set that $M$ thinks is $X$, or the set of elements that $M$ thinks are in $X$? Are the two equivalent? And which one is the standard? It appears the notation in my question is problematic.

Comment: @RedRider You should go with the descriptions in Eric's answer (and Noah's very good explanation). What I have in mind is more technical, and would probably be confusing to elaborate at this stage. In any case, "the set of elements that $M$ thinks are in $X$" is the same as "the set that $M$ thinks is $X$", at least under standard readings of the phrases. But both only make sense if there is a way to make sense of $X$ in $M$ at all, and that is where formulas come in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can certainly happen.  Here's a very easy example: consider the set $X$ defined by $X=0$ if $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ and $X=1$ otherwise.  Then $X$ is certainly in any transitive model $M$ of ZFC, since both $0$ and $1$ are.  But $X^M$ need not be the same as $X$, since $M$ need not agree with $V$ about CH.

Comment: Haha nice one! I like it!

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Consider cardinals: $\aleph_1\in L$ but frequently $\aleph_1^{L}\neq \aleph_1$. (In particular, if we force with the poset collapsing the ordinal $\aleph_1^L$ to be countable, the generic extension $V[G]$ satisfies $\aleph_1^L\neq \aleph_1^{V[G]}$.)